# How to fix Unhandled Exception setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter

```
class AlbumList extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? name;
  final String? image;
  final String? album_id;
  const AlbumList({super.key, this.name, this.image, this.album_id});



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    final albumController = Get.put(AlbumController());
    final ThemeController themeController = Get.put(ThemeController());
  final libraryController = Get.put(LibraryController());
    albumController.generatePalette(image);
    albumController.getAlbumsDetails(album_id);


    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);




    return Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox(
          key: Key("${album_id}"),
          height: Get.height,
          width: Get.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [

              // background image
              // ========================

              Obx(()=>
              albumController.isLoading.value
                    ?  Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )
                    :  SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          /// content container
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                colors:  [
                                  albumController.albumBgGradientColor2.value.withOpacity(0.8),
                                  albumController.albumBgGradientColor3.value.withOpacity(0.4),
                                  // Colors.black,
                                ],
                                stops: const [0.0, 0.3],
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [

                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 100.h,
                                ),

                                /// background image
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 200.h,
                                  width: 200.w,
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.r),
                                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                      imageUrl:albumController.songDetails['result']['image'],
                                      placeholder: (context, url) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

                                /// album details
                                SizedBox(
                                  width:Get.width,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      SizedBox(height: 10.h,),
                                      Text(
                                        albumController.songDetails['result']['label'] ?? "",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: whiteColor, fontSize: 12.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '${albumController.songDetails['result']['song_count']}  Songs | ${albumController.songDetails['result']['shared_count']} shared',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: whiteColor, fontSize: 18.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        albumController.songDetails['result']['name'] ?? "",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: whiteColor, fontSize: 20.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),

                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),


                                /// favourite icon on overlay screen
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [


                                    IconButton(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                      onPressed: () async{
                                        var res =  await  libraryController.likeOrUnlikeAlbum(album_id);
                                        if(res['status']){
                                          albumController.myLikedAlbum.contains(album_id)
                                              ? albumController.myLikedAlbum.remove(album_id)
                                              : albumController.myLikedAlbum.assign(album_id);
                                        }else{
                                          VxToast.show(context,
                                              msg: res['message'],
                                              bgColor: Colors.green,
                                              textColor: Colors.white,
                                              position: VxToastPosition.top
                                          );
                                        }
                                      },
                                      icon:  albumController.myLikedAlbum.contains(album_id)
                                          ? Icon(Icons.favorite,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                        size: 30.sp,
                                      ): Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                                        color: whiteColor,
                                        size: 30.sp,
                                      ),

                                    ),




                                    IconButton(
                                      onPressed: (){

                                      },
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.share_outlined,
                                        color: whiteColor,
                                        size: 30.sp,
                                      ),
                                    ),

                                  ],
                                ),


                                SizedBox(height: 10.h,),


                                /// list of data
                                Column(
                                  children: [
                                    ///===================================================
                                    /// song list
                                    // AlbumSongList(albumData: albumData,),

                                    ListView.builder(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        itemCount: albumController.songDetails['data'].length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          return Column(
                                            key: Key("${albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['id']}"),
                                            children: [


                                              rowHeading(
                                                  image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/NEW_-Billboard.jpg",
                                                  title: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['name'],
                                                  titleColor: whiteColor,
                                                  btncolor: txtHeadingColor,
                                                  btntxt: "SEE ALL",
                                                  btntxtcolor: whiteColor,
                                                  callback: () {
                                                    Get.to(() => AllAlbums(
                                                      title: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['name'],
                                                      category_id: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['id'],
                                                      key: const Key("album detail"),
                                                    ));
                                                  }),



                                              /// listview cards
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: (albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['is_artist']) ? 180.h : 210.h,
                                                width: Get.width,
                                                child: ListView.builder(
                                                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                                    itemCount: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['data'].length,
                                                    itemBuilder: (context, indexx) {
                                                      if (albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['is_artist']) {
                                                        return Padding(
                                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                                          child: circleCard(
                                                            artist_id: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['data'][indexx]['id'],
                                                            title: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['data'][indexx]['name'],
                                                            artist_name: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['data'][indexx]['artist_name'],
                                                            image: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['data'][indexx]['image'],
                                                            title_color:  whiteColor,
                                                            artist_name_color:  Colors.white60 ,
                                                          ),
                                                        );
                                                      } else {
                                                        return Padding(
                                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                                          child: UncheckedSquareCard(
                                                            isSong: false,
                                                            album_id: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['data'][indexx]['id'],
                                                            title: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['data'][indexx]['name'],
                                                            artist_name: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['data'][indexx]['artist_name'],
                                                            image: albumController.songDetails['data'][index]['data'][indexx]['image'],
                                                            title_color:  whiteColor,
                                                            artist_name_color:  Colors.white60,
                                                            singleSongIndex: indexx,
                                                          ),
                                                        );
                                                      }
                                                    }),
                                              ),

                                              // SizedBox(height: 10.h,),
                                            ],
                                          );
                                        }),


                                    const BottomSpace(),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),



                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
              ),




              /// appbar
              Positioned(
                top: 60.h,
                left: 20.w,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Get.back();
                  },
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_outlined,
                    color: whiteColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButtonAnimator: FloatingActionButtonAnimator.scaling,
        floatingActionButton: const PlayerInfo(),
        bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavigationWidget()
    );
  }
}
```

This Obx widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
E/flutter ( 4567): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
E/flutter ( 4567):   Obx
E/flutter ( 4567): The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
E/flutter ( 4567):   AlbumList-[<'album-id-6190eb535b04e0e54fd652744bff64f0'>]

how to fix this error

Comment: Paste the minimal code of your `albumController`

Comment: Check ```mounted``` before call setState function